Impulse force differences in Unity vs Unreal
Let's take a sphere of 30 kg on a plane. I want to make the ball jump. The gravity is set to -10 in Unity or -1000 in Unreal.
In Unity, I use this line to make my ball jump: AddForce(Vector3.up * 9 * 30, ForceMode.Impulse). The ball rises 4 meters when jumping.
In Unreal, I use this instead: AddImpulse(FVector::UpVector * 900 * 30). The ball rises 18 cm when jumping.
I'm currently taking a project from Unity to Unreal and I would like to know why there is such a big difference even if values from Unreal have been multiplied by 100 because Unreal is in cm.
According to my test, I need to call AddImpulse(FVector::UpVector * 4200 * 30) to achieve the same kind of result, so approximatly 4.5 times more force.

ok so you have found you need different numbers.. whats the actual question here?

Why behaviour is not the same even if values are the same? Physic formulas don't change and are universal no? I want to know where the difference comes from.

Note that physics systems in game engines just "mimic" the real world. In most cases they make a lot of simplifications. Though they usually try to be close to the real world. Though just to give two counter examples: In Unity "drag" is just a linear factor and not affected by the CV or area of attack. Also Unity doesn't preserve angular momentum, just angular velocity. So it doesn't represent how the real world behaves. You would never get the effect of the middle axis theorem in Unity. Can't speak for Unreal.

I finally found the issue. In Unreal, the total mass of an actor is the sum of the mass of each component of that actor.
Because I had a collider and a mesh on my ball, the mass of the sphere collider was set to 30, and the mass of the mesh was auto-calculated because I didn't override the value. By setting the mass of the mesh to 0, I now have similar behavior with both engines.

I have never used Unreal, so I don't know what units they actually work with. Unity tries to stick as close as possible to the real world. Force uses Newtons (kgm/s²), an impulse uses kgm/s. When you apply an impulse force in Unity, you effectively just add a certain amount of velocity (over here I explained the 4 different force modes in Unity)
A quick google search verified that Unreal usually uses centimeter as base unit, but that doesn't seem to be always the case as their own games (Unreal Tournament) uses 2cm / unit. So I don't know how the units and unit conversions and conventions work in Unreal.
Assuming the values you mentioned, in Unity when gravity is set to 10m/s² and you essentially set the initial velocity to 9m/s (as a result of your impulse force) we would get a time of 0.9s until we reach the apex. The distance travelled would be 1/2*a*t² so it's 1/2 * 10m/s² * (0.9s)² which gives us a height of 4.05m. So this appears to be correct when no friction or drag is applied.
As I said I'm not familiar with Unreal, so I have no idea how you end up with 18cm. Maybe there is something like drag applied in Unreal?

You can add drag but I set it to 0 on my ball in Unreal. So yeah it makes sense in Unity but no sense in Unreal.
